# How long to travel fixed distance with variable velocity?

Tags: calculus, physics

Suppose we have an underwater robot that can travel at a fixed velocity, v, if there is no current. This robot needs to travel a fixed distance, d. While in the water, the current acts on the robot affecting its velocity. The current varies over time. How do we determine how long it takes for the robot to travel d? That is, can we get a general equation for time given d and v?

Comment: Distance covered is the integral of velocity.

Comment: @EthanBolker Not quite: the integral of velocity is displacement. Distance covered is the integral of speed.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes. My error. I suspect the OP meant displacement.

Comment: At any given instant, is the current the same everywhere (that is, it is a function of time **only** and not location)? Does the robot travel a fixed path? Is that path a straight line? Do we know what the current was at every instant? Is the current always directly along the robot's path or can it cross the robot's path? If there is a cross current, how does the robot stay on path?

Comment: It's important to be completely explicit about the conditions for a solution. For example, if the robot's goal is simply to travel a path of length $d$, where the shape and direction of the path doesn't matter, then the robot should always travel in the same direction as the current, which will maximize its speed and minimize the time to generate a path of length $d$. I think this is probably not what you want, but you have not said so.

Comment: @DavidK yes the robot attempts to travel along a straight line between point an and point b. I should have been clearer about that. The current can vary at different locations and times, so nothing can be guaranteed. If there is a cross-current, it will continue to travel directly to point b. We can assume the current will not be strong enough to prevent the robot from reaching its destination.

Answer (score 1):

Total speed: $$v_t= c(t)+v_r$$ where $c$ is the function of the current and $v_r$ is  the fixed velocity you mentioned.

Integrating:
$$\int_0^x(c(t)+v)dt = \int_0^x v dt + \int_0^x c(t) dt = vx + C(x)-C(0) + U$$
Where $x$ is the time it would take for the robot to cover the distance $d$, $C(x)$ is the integral of $c(x)$, and $U$ is the integration constant.

Now solving for x:
$$ vx + C(x) - C(0) = d$$
It is quite obvious that the solution of the equation vastly depends on $c(t)$.

**Note:  $U = 0$**. This is the general solution.

Comment: This is correct if distance is the net distance covered, not the actual total taking backward movement into account. The answer is the same as long as the current does not cancel the forward velocity. See comments to the question.

Comment: @EthanBolker That is absolutely true